# How to increment a key value pair in JSON file

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file that I would need a certain value to be incremented. Here is the JSON file structure I have.

```
{
    "Body": {
        "Content": {

        },
        "Lines": [{
            "LineNumber": "1",
            "DateOfService": "10/20/2017"

        },
        {
            "LineNumber": "1",
            "DateOfService": "10/20/2017"

        },
        {
            "LineNumber": "1",
            "DateOfService": "10/20/2017"

        }]
    }
}
```

I want the "LineNumber" values to be set from 1 and incremented by 1 subsequently. I have close to a 1000 lines.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Share the code you've already tried.

Comment: The Json in your question isn't valid. Please provide at least a valid Json. Furthermore it would be easier to help you, if you provide some code snippets you already tried out.

Comment: What is invalid with the file? I used an online JSON formatter and it did not throw any errors with the file. I haven't tried any code and I am not familliar with powershell.

Comment: I think @rufer7 means that as presented, your JSON is not a minima, complete, verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user176047 If I validate your Json you pasted into the question above using https://jsonlint.com/ the validation fails. There are 2 closing curly braces missing at the end and there are commas after "DateOfService": "10/20/2017", which are not valid

Comment: You are correct...I should have used the complete file but it is too big so i snipped.

Comment: So you should edit to provide a valid sample that can be used by others to reproduce your results.

Comment: I have edited to correct the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$InputFile = "path\name.json.txt"
$OutPutFile = "path\name.new.json"

$objJsonFile = Get-Content -Raw -Path $InputFile | ConvertFrom-Json

$intLine = 1

foreach ($itmLine in $objJsonFile.Claim.Lines)
{
    $itmLine.LineNumber = [string]$intLine++

}

$objJsonFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Out-File $OutPutFile
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to do so using the following code.

```
$fileContent = Get-Content PATH\TO\FILE.json;
$json = $fileContent | ConvertFrom-Json;

$counter = 1;
ForEach($line in $json.Body.Lines) {
    $line.LineNumber = $counter;
    $counter++;
}

# write json back to file!?
```